# Plotly timelapse graph not playing after embedding it into a Hugo webpage

Tags: plotly, interactive, hugo, plotly-express

I embedded a interactive plotly graph into a Hugo webpage using the instructions found [here](https://www.rodened.com/posts/how-to-display-charts-on-a-static-web-site-with-node-red/). The simplified instructions I used are below the cut (could be helpful to anyone who needs a simpler instructional in the future).

After finishing all these steps, I was able to see the graph on the rendering of my webpage, but unfortunately the graph isn't 'playable'. It just appears, and I can zoom in and out so it's 'interactive', but the play button doesn't result in progression of the data.

Here's the repo for the example site if needed (git clone, download hugo, and use `hugo server` in dir to render page): https://github.com/kc-tal/hugo-plotly-example

---

**Step 1**: Write your plotly graph into a json file using `fig.write_json('<path/filename.json')`. Make sure to place the json file in your `<homefolder>/static` folder in your Hugo template

**Step 2**: Create both a `load-plotly.html` and `plotly.html` shortcode files with the code found in the link under `<homefolder>/layouts/shortcodes`. Make a folder if one doesn't already exist.

**Step 3**: Under `<homefolder>/layouts` create a partials folder. Within that create a `head.html` file and copy and paste the contents of what is found in the themes native `head.html` file found in `<homefolder>/<theme name>/layouts/partials/head.html`. Then at the bottom, add the corresponding code found in the link.

**Step 3**: For whichever page needs the plotly graph, make sure to add `plotly: true` in the front matter (ie where the title, date, etc. goes at the top of a markdown file)